# Angular's Resource Promise is not re-rendering when data loaded

Tags: javascript, binding, angularjs, promise, angularjs-scope

I am new to AngularJS and am having trouble to get resource's promise to re-render the view when the data is loaded.  This results in the {{}} getting replaced with blanks (from the promise) but then the view just stays that way.

I have seen a lot of examples of problems with promises being solved with $apply, $digest, $watch etc., and am open to these suggestions be would love to know the root problem with my approach.  Here is my controller code

```
<div ng-controller='pook'>
<p>There are {{posts.length}} posts</p>
<div ng-repeat='post in posts'>
    <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
    <div>{{post.text}}</div>
    <a href='/readPost/{{post.id}}'>More</a>
    |  -
    <a href='/editPost/{{post.id}}'>Edit</a>
    |  -
    <a href='/deletePost/{{post.id}}'>Delete</a>
</div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>function pook($scope, $http, $route, $routeParams, $resource)
{
/*Approach #1 does work
$http.post('/').success(function(data, status, headers, config)
{
  $scope.posts = data.posts;
});
*/

var User = $resource('/');

/*Approach #2 does work
User.save('', function(data)
{
  $scope.posts = data.posts;
})
*/

//Approach #3 does NOT work -> renders blanks and never re-renders on loaded data
$scope.posts = User.save().posts
}
</script>
```

My loaded scripts are

//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js'
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular-resource.min.js'

Description of the promise behavior that I want is here
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

Comment: It looks as though you need to spend a little more time learning how to structure your angular code. Also be aware that $resource 'creates a resource object that lets you interact with RESTful server-side data sources' (from the angular documentation). From your example it doesn't look like you're calling a restful service. If you just want to make a regular ajax call, then use the low level $http service and wrap it in a custom service to catch any errors before they break your application. Check out http://www.yearofmoo.com for this and other useful examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your fetch to:

```
var User = $resource('/');
$scope.postsResponse = User.$save();
```

and your bind to:

```
<div ng-repeat='post in posts'>
  <h3>{{postResponse.post.title}}</h3>
  <div>{{postResponse.post.text}}</div>
</div>
```

As angular is based on promises, it is possible to bind the response of an $http or $resource action directly to the HTML, and when it gets resolved, angular changes the properties.

If possible, remove the wrapper from the server response (`{posts: []}` to `[]`). If you do this, you'll need to hint the resource that the response is an array. Look at the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) for more info.

The error happens because when you call a method on the resource, it returns a hollow object, so there is no `.posts` at it. But if you bind it to your code, angular will wait until it gets there.

This is all you should do at front end, **are you sure the server answers what is expected**? **Are you sure you need a post to retrieve the data**?

Comment: Absolutely **brilliant**.  Works like a charm.  I get it now: the promise doesn't have a "posts" key so the binding isn't taking effect.  I need to bind the (entire) promise to the html and then specify in the html where the data will be located within the promise. Alternatively, removing the post key from the server and using isArray: true also worked. Finally to your point and @supermasher about code quality, my apologies, this is only example code - i know that getting data with POST is not exactly restful.

Comment: @user1649082 I don’t think you are using the term “promise” correctly. A “promise” is not your model. $resources only uses promises *internally* to eventually update the contents of the array it returned to you. All a promise is is an object with a `then` function you can pass callbacks to.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the Restangular library and it can be configured to account for nested responses.